# Swift - Remove white spaces from string doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i'm trying to remove white spaces and some characters from a string, please check my code below

```
// giving phoneString = +39 333 3333333
var phoneString = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, indexPhone).takeRetainedValue() as! String

// Remove spaces from string
phoneString = phoneString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

// Remove +39 if exist
if phoneString.rangeOfString("+39") != nil{
    phoneString = phoneString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\0", withString: "+39", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}

print(phoneString) // output +39 333 3333333
```

it seems like all the changes has no effect over my string, why this happen?

**EDIT @V S**

[image: screen]

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to convert my string in utf 8, check the result:

```
43 51 57 194 160 51 51 51 194 160 51 51 51 51 51 51 51
```

where:

```
43 = +
51 = 3
57 = 9
160 = space
194 = wtf?!? is this?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what do you try to do is

```
// your input string
let str = "+39 333 3333333"

let arr = str.characters.split(" ").map(String.init) // ["+39", "333", "3333333"]
// remove country code and reconstruct the rest as one string without whitespaces
let str2 = arr.dropFirst().joinWithSeparator("") // "3333333333"
```

to filter out country code, only if exists (as Eendje asks)

```
let str = "+39 123 456789"
let arr = str.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
let str3 = arr.filter { !$0.hasPrefix("+") }.joinWithSeparator("") // "123456789"
```

UPDATE, based on your update.
160 represents no-breakable space. just modify next line in my code

```
let arr = str.characters.split{" \u{00A0}".characters.contains($0)}.map(String.init)
```

there is `" \u{00A0}".characters.contains($0)` expression where you can extend the string to as much whitespace characters, as you need. 160 is \u{00A0} see [details here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Whitespace_character).

**Update for Swift 4**

String.characters is deprecated. So the correct answer would now be

```
// your input string
let str = "+39 333 3333333"

let arr = str.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces) // ["+39", "333", "3333333"]
// remove country code and reconstruct the rest as one string without whitespaces
let str2 = arr.dropFirst().joined() // "3333333333"
```

Comment: What if the string doesn't contain "+39"? :)

Comment: @Mono.WTF is this, what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mono.WTF 160 represents unicode no-break space .... OK, I see now your trouble, will update my answer in few minutes :-)

Comment: @Mono.WTF sometimes we do not see the forest for the trees , it becomes :-)

Comment: can anyone tell why it doesn't replace the whitespace in the first place?

Comment: @vmzi See what this 160 in his byte stream is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen

Comment: weird thing is that it works just fine on my phone, but it fails to replace the white space on the simulator

Comment: @vmzi give me the byte stream of your data, will check it. or better, share somewhere your code

Comment: I need to use ```components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)``` to trim white spaces in this string *ee eiuiue ppop MM LL   DD*. There are white spaces(some from unicode chars) in it but can be detected by contains(" ")

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 / Swift 4**

```
let withoutSpaces = phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only *trims* the string - i.e. removes leading & trailing spaces - you need to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` replacing " " with "".

Secondly, your parameters on `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` for the country code are the wrong way round.

Thirdly, "\0" is not what you want- that's ASCII null, not zero.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
//MARK:- 3 ways to resolve it
var tempphone = "0345 55500 93"

//MARK:- No 1
tempphone = tempphone.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

//MARK:- No 2
tempphone = tempphone.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

//MARK:- No 3
tempphone = tempphone.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
phoneString = phoneString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+39", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)


phoneString = phoneString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

Comment: @Mono.WTF, Check it.

Comment: same output, nothing changes

Comment: Can I see Log, print phoneString, before first line, after first line and last. and add Screenshot,

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This has worked for me:

```
if phoneString.rangeOfString("+39") != nil{
            freshString = phoneString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\0", withString: "+39", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        }

        var strings = freshString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ") as NSArray
        var finalString = strings.componentsJoinedByString("")
        //outputs +393333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this replace the whitespace

`phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00A0}", with: "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
let trimmedPhoneString = String(phoneString).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

To Remove +39 if exist, you can use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString instead

Comment: same output, nothing changes

Comment: Dude, stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet can trim the trailing or leading white spaces if any. check the apple docs. As i said you can use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Answer (score 0):

```
var phoneString = "+39 333 3333333"
phoneString = phoneString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString:"")
if phoneString.rangeOfString("+39") != nil
{
    phoneString = phoneString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+39", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}
print(phoneString) // output 3333333333
```

Comment: my output is: " 333 3333333"